# Checking repeating combination

Tags: php, loops

So I have a program in PHP, which draws three numbers from array, adds them up and checks if `sum = 10`. If yes, then it should print those numbers on the display.

What I want to do is to check which combination was drawn. For example:

```
First draw: 1+7+2
Second draw: 5+4+1
Third draw: 1+2+7
```

First and third had the same numbers, so third shouldn't be shown. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do it.

My code:

```
<?PHP
 $numb = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0);

 $hm = count($numb);

 for ($a=0; $a<$hm;$a++)
  for ($b=0; $b<$hm;$b++)
   for ($c=0; $c<$hm;$c++)
   {
    $cnt = $numb[$a]+$numb[$b]+$numb[$c];

    if ($cnt == 10)
    {
     print_r ($numb[$a]);
     echo "+";
     print_r ($numb[$b]);
     echo "+";
     print_r ($numb[$c]);
     echo "<br>";
    }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Inputs are numbers from array $numb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the provided code, you can simply draw numbers "in order" to avoid duplicates:

```
$numb = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);     // <-- must be sorted from lowest to highest

for ($a = 0; $a < $hm; $a++) 
     for ($b = $a; $b < $hm; $b++)      // <-- start from $a
         for ($c = $b; $c < $hm; $c++)  // <-- start from $b
```

Thus, the combination 1+2+7 is possible, but not 1+7+2, and also not 7+1+2 etc.

Comment: appreciated i get his question wrongly Niko great work